# Finding a single frequency in an sound file xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frequency

For an app I'm working on a i need to be able to 'search' a sound file to find a particular frequency.

Basically, the iPhone mic records for 5 seconds writes to an a lossless music file. I then need to 'open' that file and search for a particular frequency. The frequency is very particular (eg not between 15hz and 300hz, its is a fixed number).
Also, as soon the the frequency is found the search can stop.

I've got the iPhone recording the sound and writing to the file, I am just unsure how to open that file and search for the frequency.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a pure tone, or is it a complex sound, e.g. music or speech, where you are looking for a specific pitch within the complex sound ?

Comment: It is a pure tone that i am looking for.

Comment: OK - in that case Goertzel is probably the way to go - see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [PitchDetector](https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector) and the related [tutorial](http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/).
Can't get you any closer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a specific, fixed, pure tone then the simplest method is probably [Goertzel's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) - it's very simple to implement and is relatively lightweight computationally compared to using e.g. an FFT or autocorrelation method.